# What is the difference between "novi" and "scio"?

Tags: verbs, word-comparison

Latin has at least two words that straightforwardly translate to English "know":

- *novi* (perf. of [*nosco*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnosco))
- [*scio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dscio)

Plautus combines the two pleonastically:

> nec vos qui homines sitis novi nec scio

Here's one way of asking my question: **Are there any meanings that are not shared between these two words?** If so, can you give examples of cases where one would be appropriate but not the other?

Comment: I don't think that is pleonasm. I'd translate as 'I haven't met and know nothing about'.

Comment: I didn't realize at first that you are comparing one verb in perfect tense with one in present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite a large question, to which a comprehensive answer is easily found in the more comprehensive dictionaries under **Know**, with copious examples. However, in direct answer, there certainly are meanings not shared between the two, which I will try to summarise, although it is worth pointing out that the differences in usage can be very slight.

**Scio** is the most general word, meaning that you have a certainty, or at least clearly perceive, some fact(s) or other. It is followed by the kinds of clause that you would expect: acc. +  inf., *de* + abl., relative + subj., neuter pronoun, and so on. Its opposite **nescio**, (‘not to know’, ‘be unaware/ignorant of’ etc.) is used similarly. But *scio* (and *nescio*) can also have the sense of ‘know how to …’ (particularly where it refers to a skill) as in *scio scribere*, *nescio aratro uti*.

The simple idea behind ‘not to know’ is expressed by **ignoro** (this being possibly more definite than *nescio*, which can be qualified by, for example, a clause after *quin*). The opppsite of *ignoro* is **nosco**, meaning ‘am acquainted with’, which is more usually seen in the perfect tenses, still giving a present sense in English. To claim a personal acquaintance, say, you might appropriately introduce yourself with *te novi*, or *me no(ve)ris*.

With, I think, a shade of meaning rather more active than that of simply learning (for which *disco*/*didici*  or *certior fieri* is appropriate), the verb for  the sense of ‘getting to know’ or ‘finding out’ is **cognosco**, most often in the perfect tenses to imply the knowledge for which *scio* in the present might sometimes be used equally well. **Comperio** is different again, with the sense of ‘know for certain’ or ‘tried and tested by experience’; *compertum habet* = ‘he knows without doubt’.

Answer (score 2):

This is only an educated guess of a partial answer, but in line with Tom's more general answer, I think.

*Disclaimer: My knowledge of the issue is not deep nor technical, and could be biased by the Spanish verbs* conocer *and* saber *which are* to some extent *valid translations of nosco and scio respectively.*<sup>1</sup> Please let me know if I am mistaken.

---

I would use **novi** (not scio) to mean **to have met someone**.

- [Notus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnotus1) is the participle of nosco and in a specific sense [means](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnosco) acquaintance, friend (at least post-Classically, L&S only lists the plural **noti** in this sense). It seems to me that there is no parallel with [scio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dscio) for this meaning.
- From the definitions, it seems that one can *scire* and *noscere* something, but only *noscere* someone.
- I can find examples of novi+person, but none of scio+person without some deed by that person being the thing that is actually known.

Example:

> **Novi** enim **te**, **novi patrem**, novi domum nomenque vestrum ([Cic. Lig. 5](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Cic.%20Lig.%205&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)) / *for **I know you**, **I know your father**, I know your birth and your name*

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm well aware that *conocer* is derived from co-*gnoscere* and *saber* from *sapere*, but that is not my point.