# Translating "Father knows beer best" into Latin

Tags: sentence-translation, english-to-latin-translation, motto

I'm making a label for my dad's homebrew as a Christmas gift and I'd love to include "Father knows beer best" in Latin as the motto of his company. Could anybody help translate that for me?

Answer (score 16):

I'd go for a wordplay:

> **Pater optime cerevisiam sapit**

- Just as the other answers, **pater** is straightforwardly *father*
- The verb [**sapio**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsapio) means both *to taste* and *to know/understand*. Hence **sapit** is the right conjugation to speak about a third person (a "he", the father) who knows.
- In Latin you have different words for knowing. Not sure how to describe them in English, but I'll try: **sapio** and **scio** are somewhat better for knowledge in general, while **nosco** is better for getting acquainted or getting to know something. If you know any Spanish, it's like the difference between *saber* and *conocer*. See [What is the difference between "novi" and "scio"?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7249/what-is-the-difference-between-novi-and-scio) for better explanations in English.
- **cerevisia** is literally *beer*. The -m ending makes it the object of **sapit**.
- **optime** is the adverb for *best*. You need an adverb to modify the verb. In this context, English *best* may work as a superlative of both an adjective (good) or an adverb (well). In Latin there are (slightly) different words for that.
- In Latin, word order is not rigid as long as meaning is unambiguously expressed though other means (e.g., word endings).

Regarding your question about *father knows best*, the issue here is the same I said above: you have to use the adverbial *best* (**optime**, so-to-say **most well*), or change it for something else, or add a word or two to use the adejctival *best* (**optimus, -a, -um**, **most good* + sth.) For example, father knows what's best, father knows the best things).

A possible translation could be **pater optima sapit**, where **optima** is an adjective, neuter in gender, and plural: a common way of referring to *things* that have certain trait (adjective). **Optima** doesn't change as the object of sapit. The full sentence would mean, *Father knows the best things*. Or you could stick to the adverb and get **pater optime sapit**, *father knows best* (or **most well* if you allow the distinction).

Comment: Since "sapio" also means "taste", it adds an extra layer of meaning since the object is beer

Comment: +1 for the double meaning, very clever.

Comment: Double meaning aside, why not *nosco*? From both my knowledge and your explanation, it fits better.

Comment: @pacholik, I also think it fits somewhat better, but since both fit, I chose the double meaning.

Answer (score 5):

*Pater de cerevisia peritissimus* should do it.

Literally, this means 'Father about beer is very experienced'.

Comment: You could also use a genitive with peritissimus: pater cerevisiae peritissimus.

Comment: @cnread Or even _ad_ with accusative: pater ad cerevisiam coquendam peritissimus.If he's brewing his own, I prefer my first effort, which I think better suggests an experience of brewing, rather than of beer in general — a fine point, I know!